# How to fetch and show pdf file stored in s3 in HTML canvas a using jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, jspdf

How can i download a pdf stored in s3 and load it in to canvas. so i can make some changes to it and download in after that ?

I have tried Jspdf but looks like it does not have option to use a pdf in a remote location. PDFjs can download pdf stored in remote, but does not have the capability to generating pdf from canvas

is it possible to load a pfd stored in s3 to canvas and make a downloadable with jsPDF alone ? if not how can i do it ?

Comment: Can you post a sample S3 URL to pdf? Also if your S3 bucket doesn't allow CORS requests you won't be able to request that pdf from client-side no matter what.

Comment: Due to my company policies i am not allowed to post those pdf links. The CORS are configured properly.

Comment: If you can put just an arbitrary pdf on S3 with CORS enabled I can post a working sample in the response.

Comment: i have added a sample pdf file in this location [file](https://s3.amazonaws.com/the-post-man/Nijeesh'sResume.pdf)

Comment: I'm still getting: `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/....pdf' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

This might be your main problem in general btw.

Comment: i think i failed to explain my question clearly.  I am not bothered about where the file come from. dont have to be s3 maybe even any file server will do. My problem is i dont have any means of fetching the file from any remote source and showing it on canvas. I know PDFjs can do this. what i am asking is can JSpdf do it ?

Comment: You won't be able to load pdf from any remote service, if it doesn't have CORS enabled. Other than that `JSpdf` should be [able to load pdf from any url](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/module-fileloading.html#~loadFile) just fine.